# noun after "to"

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, complementation

What does the following sentence means? "have to" is succeeded by a non-verb group. Is that correct?

> The access smartphones have to vast amounts of information poses some
>   drawbacks.

Comment: They *have* access *to* information... (vast amounts of it)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Have to* is an accidental collocation, not the verbal idiom = *must*.

Parse it like this:

> The access [which] smartphones have . . .

What kind of access?

> access to vast amounts of information

That is, smartphones *have access to vast amounts of information*.

Comment: Actually it would be "that", not "which".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Nope. Relative *that* is used only with restrictive clauses, but *wh-* words may be used with both restrictive and nonrestrictive clauses.

Comment: o.O never heard that before. "Which" is only used with non-restrictive clauses in my country. That's _England_, by the way. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think not. A lot of style manuals adopted as a "rule" the Fowlers' 1906 suggestion that the two relatives be distinguished by use, and spoken English (when it employs a relativizer at all) tends to prefer *that* in all contexts. In consequence, restrictive *which* has been increasing steadily for 50 years in writing, passing *which* around 1990; but the "rule" was never widely accepted, and is ignored or scorned by modern linguistics-based grammars.  Restrictive *which* is still very much alive on both sides of the Atlantic, particularly in less colloquial registers.

Comment: Alright good for you then

Answer (score 3):

This is a poorly worded sentence, but what this sentence means is this:

The sentence is talking about access.  The simplest form of the sentence is this:

**Access poses drawbacks**.

Adding some additional words, we'd get:

(The) **access** **poses** (some) **drawbacks**.

Then we just add some additional words to describe the access:

(The) **access** [smartphones have] **poses** (some) **drawbacks**.

Finally, the writer throws in a prepositional phrase to further describe the access which the smartphones have:

(The) **access** [smartphones have] {*to vast amounts of information*} **poses** (some) **drawbacks**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's poorly worded, just that it has some potentially confusing aspects.

Comment: That's fair.  A sentence that has potentially confusing aspects was always described by my mother (an English teacher) as "poorly worded."  I apologize for bringing my baggage to the table!

Comment: I think it mostly depends on the extent of the possible confusion and the context; almost any poetry, for example, might confuse most learners, but that doesn't mean it's badly worded, just that it's very sophisticated. And a research paper's dense English isn't necessarily much of a problem either.

Comment: The main confusion is from leaving out the "that", as in "the access that smartphones have".

Comment: Apart from everything else, the singular "poses" after two plurals "smartphones" and "amounts" is a bit of a shock, even though it's grammatically correct.